# How to keep Spark cluster alive between spark2-submits?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I need to process input data files as and when they arrive by doing a spark2-submit to process the input files through pyspark script. What I have observed is that for every spark2--submit, spark does a lot of initialization before doing the latest input file's data processing. This results in delay. How can I keep the Spark cluster alive between spark2-submits?

Separate but related question: Apart from spark2-submit, what other mechanisms can be used to submit payloads to spark?

Thanks in advance for your insights.

Comment: What Spark scheduler are you using?

Answer (score 0):

**Cluster**

Unless you use Spark in `local` mode (there is really no cluster there) cluster is preserved between different applications.

**SparkContext and SparkSession**

Are local objects. There cannot live longer than the application. If initialization time is unacceptable you can adjust your application to use application serve like Livy.